# Openssl client certificate ocsp stapling in client

Tags: c++, c, openssl

I am working on a project where both the server and client side send certificates for mutual authentication. For the revocation part server can always use ocsp stapling and the client can verify that, but I couldn't find any way to add an ocsp stapling response for the client. Is that even possible in the OpenSSL library?